# How to load static image using Glide in android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-glide

Im using glide to presenting a banner in my application. Although it worked on URL string, but I want it to use static images instead.

I have a image `test.jpg` in `/res/drawable`. I tried replace the url string with `/res/drawable/test.jpg` but it wont work.

Here is the code:

```
 Glide.with(viewHolder.itemView)
                        .load("https://laz-img-cdn.alicdn.com/images/ims-web/TB1pHADjBr0gK0jSZFnXXbRRXXa.jpg_1200x1200.jpg")
                        .fitCenter()
                        .into(viewHolder.imageViewBackground);
```

Comment: no need to use Glide , you can directly set using `viewHolder.imageViewBackground.setImageResource(R.drawable.test)`

Comment: Try using `Glide.with(this).load(R.drawable.my_drawable_image_name).into(myImageView);
`

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using Coil Library because its new and simple to use.
for you issue use this code

```
Glide.with(viewHolder.itemView)
        .load(R.drawable.test)
        .into(viewHolder.imageViewBackground)
```

Comment: There shouldn't be any need to do this with Glide. I don't know why someone would need to use a library. Android's ImageView has a `setImageResource()` method that you can use to dynamically set the bitmap in that ImageView. You probably would use a library when you are fetching it from a remote server online or when you are trying to retrieve the images that exist in the Android device's external or shared storage.

Comment: But to use `setImageResource` you might want to consider reducing the resolution and quality of the image and provide an alternate image resource for low-resolution devices

Comment: @Noah well said. the imageView has already predefined function to provide a bitmap or drawable resource but when when we considering using a library we use for the future developing changes for instance when we get an image from the device storage or when we get an image as `URL`, so all of these cases we need a library for it. so when we use the library there is no reason to not use it for the imageView and it gives better quality for the image as you said. thanks for the comment.